# Rust returnig iterator with trait bound on its items

Tags: rust, rayon, rust-ndarray

I am trying to write a common interface for different types of matrices that provides a way to mutably iterate their rows and modify them. I have the following matrix types:

```
struct NdArrayMatrix {
    matrix: Array2<f32>,
}

struct ByteMatrix<'a> {
    data: &'a mut [u8],
    rows: usize,
    cols: usize,
}
```

Where the first one is just a RAM-stored matrix, and the second is memory mapped, using the MMap library, but for convenience, I omit those details. First, I made a trait to be able to modify both of them using the same interface:

```
trait ReadWrite
{
    fn rw_read(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> f32;
    fn rw_write(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize, val: f32);
}
```

Then, I've created a trait that produces a `rayon::iter::IndexedParallelItertor` from both of these:

```
trait Sliceable<'a>
{
    type Output: IndexedParallelIterator;

    fn rows_par_iter(&'a mut self ) -> Self::Output;
}
```

Up to this point works everything fine. But when I want to use these in a generic context, such as:

```
fn<'a, T> slice_and_write(matrix: T)
where T: Sliceable<'a>
{
    T.rows_par_iter()
     .map(|mut row| {
          row.rw_write(...);
     })
     ...
}
```

I run into problems. It is obvious, that row, in this case, doesn't implement `ReadWrite` so no surprise there. So what I tried to do, is to create an iterator trait based on `IndexedParallelItertor`:

```
trait RwIterator: IndexedParallelIterator {
    type Item: ReadWrite;
}
```

and modify `Sliceable`:

```
trait Sliceable<'a>
{
    type Output: RwIterator;

    fn rows_par_iter(&'a mut self ) -> Self::Output;
}
```

Running this I get the error:

```
   |  row.rw_write(...);
   |      ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `<<T as Sliceable<'a>>::Output as ParallelIterator>::Item`
```

Which is, again, fairly obvious. I suspect that the `map` function does only require the trait bound ParallelIterator, hence can't take advantage of the trait `RwIterator`.

**My question is:** Is there any way around this problem, or an alternate way for doing this?

**EDIT:**
Here is a minimal reproducible code example, only using one of the matrix structures.

```
use ndarray::Array2;
use rayon::prelude::*;
use ndarray::Axis;
use ndarray::parallel::Parallel;
use ndarray::Dim;
use ndarray::iter::AxisIterMut;
use rayon::iter::ParallelIterator;
use ndarray::ViewRepr;
use ndarray::ArrayBase;

struct NdArrayMatrix {
    matrix: Array2<f32>,
}

impl NdArrayMatrix {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let matrix = Array2::zeros((10, 10));
        
        Self {
            matrix,
        }
    }
}

trait ReadWrite
{
    fn rw_read(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> f32;
    fn rw_write(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize, val: f32);
}

impl ReadWrite for NdArrayMatrix {
    fn rw_read(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> f32 {
        self.matrix[[i, j]]
    }

    fn rw_write(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize, val: f32) {
        self.matrix[[i, j]] = val;
    }
}

impl ReadWrite for ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&mut f32>, Dim<[usize; 1]>> {
    fn rw_read(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> f32 {
        self[j]
    }

    fn rw_write(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize, val: f32) {
        self[j] = val;
    }
}

trait RwIterator: IndexedParallelIterator {
    type Item: ReadWrite;
}

impl<'a> RwIterator for Parallel<AxisIterMut<'a, f32, Dim<[usize; 1]>>> {
    type Item =  ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&'a mut f32>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>;
}

trait Sliceable<'a>
{
    type Output: RwIterator;

    fn rows_par_iter(&'a mut self ) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<'a> Sliceable<'a> for NdArrayMatrix {
    type Output = Parallel<AxisIterMut<'a, f32, Dim<[usize; 1]>>>;

    fn rows_par_iter(&'a mut self) -> Self::Output {
        self.matrix
            .axis_iter_mut(Axis(0))
            .into_par_iter()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut matrix: NdArrayMatrix = NdArrayMatrix::new();

    test(matrix);
}

fn test<'a, T> (matrix: T)
where T: Sliceable<'a> + ReadWrite
{
    matrix.rows_par_iter()
        .map(|mut row| {
            row.rw_write(0, 0, 0.0);
        }).count();
}
```

Comment: Would you mind providing a full [minimal reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that produces the error you show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is 90% there.

The problem you are facing is that `RwIterator::Item` is `ReadWrite`, but nowhere does your code constrain that `RwIterator::Item` has to be the same as the `ParallelIterator::Item` of the same object.

To fix this, you can annotate it manually:

```rust
trait RwIterator: IndexedParallelIterator<Item = <Self as RwIterator>::Item> {
    type Item: ReadWrite;
}

impl<'a> RwIterator for Parallel<AxisIterMut<'a, f32, Dim<[usize; 1]>>> {
    type Item = ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&'a mut f32>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>;
}
```

With that, Rust now understands the connection.

Some other minor adjustments were necessary as well. Here is a version that compiles:

```rust
use ndarray::iter::AxisIterMut;
use ndarray::parallel::Parallel;
use ndarray::Array2;
use ndarray::ArrayBase;
use ndarray::Axis;
use ndarray::Dim;
use ndarray::ViewRepr;
use rayon::iter::ParallelIterator;
use rayon::prelude::*;

struct NdArrayMatrix {
    matrix: Array2<f32>,
}

impl NdArrayMatrix {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let matrix = Array2::zeros((10, 10));

        Self { matrix }
    }
}

trait ReadWrite {
    fn rw_read(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> f32;
    fn rw_write(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize, val: f32);
}

impl ReadWrite for NdArrayMatrix {
    fn rw_read(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> f32 {
        self.matrix[[i, j]]
    }

    fn rw_write(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize, val: f32) {
        self.matrix[[i, j]] = val;
    }
}

impl ReadWrite for ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&mut f32>, Dim<[usize; 1]>> {
    fn rw_read(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> f32 {
        self[j]
    }

    fn rw_write(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize, val: f32) {
        self[j] = val;
    }
}

trait RwIterator: IndexedParallelIterator<Item = <Self as RwIterator>::Item> {
    type Item: ReadWrite;
}

impl<'a> RwIterator for Parallel<AxisIterMut<'a, f32, Dim<[usize; 1]>>> {
    type Item = ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&'a mut f32>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>;
}

trait Sliceable<'a> {
    type Output: RwIterator;

    fn rows_par_iter(&'a mut self) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<'a> Sliceable<'a> for NdArrayMatrix {
    type Output = Parallel<AxisIterMut<'a, f32, Dim<[usize; 1]>>>;

    fn rows_par_iter(&'a mut self) -> Self::Output {
        self.matrix.axis_iter_mut(Axis(0)).into_par_iter()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let matrix: NdArrayMatrix = NdArrayMatrix::new();

    test(matrix);
}

fn test<T>(mut matrix: T)
where
    for<'a> T: Sliceable<'a>,
{
    matrix
        .rows_par_iter()
        .map(|mut row| {
            row.rw_write(0, 0, 0.0);
        })
        .count();
}
```

---

### Little Excurse

All of this is only necessary because associated types cannot be annotated with trait bounds yet.

This might change if [RFC 2289](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2289-associated-type-bounds.html) gets stabilized at some point.

Then, you might be able to completely delete the `RwIterator` trait and specify it like this instead:

```rust
type Output: ParallelIterator<Item: ReadWrite>;
```

No guarantees on that one, though. I didn't get it to work with the `nightly` compiler yet.

You can already kind of emulate that behaviour, with some boilerplate code:

```rust
use ndarray::iter::AxisIterMut;
use ndarray::parallel::Parallel;
use ndarray::Array2;
use ndarray::ArrayBase;
use ndarray::Axis;
use ndarray::Dim;
use ndarray::ViewRepr;
use rayon::iter::ParallelIterator;
use rayon::prelude::*;

struct NdArrayMatrix {
    matrix: Array2<f32>,
}

impl NdArrayMatrix {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let matrix = Array2::zeros((10, 10));

        Self { matrix }
    }
}

trait ReadWrite {
    fn rw_read(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> f32;
    fn rw_write(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize, val: f32);
}

impl ReadWrite for NdArrayMatrix {
    fn rw_read(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> f32 {
        self.matrix[[i, j]]
    }

    fn rw_write(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize, val: f32) {
        self.matrix[[i, j]] = val;
    }
}

impl ReadWrite for ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&mut f32>, Dim<[usize; 1]>> {
    fn rw_read(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> f32 {
        self[j]
    }

    fn rw_write(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize, val: f32) {
        self[j] = val;
    }
}

trait Sliceable<'a> {
    type Item: ReadWrite;
    type Output: ParallelIterator<Item = Self::Item>;

    fn rows_par_iter(&'a mut self) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<'a> Sliceable<'a> for NdArrayMatrix {
    // Sadly needs explicit type annotation for `Item`
    type Item = ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&'a mut f32>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>;
    type Output = Parallel<AxisIterMut<'a, f32, Dim<[usize; 1]>>>;

    fn rows_par_iter(&'a mut self) -> Self::Output {
        self.matrix.axis_iter_mut(Axis(0)).into_par_iter()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let matrix: NdArrayMatrix = NdArrayMatrix::new();

    test(matrix);
}

fn test<T>(mut matrix: T)
where
    for<'a> T: Sliceable<'a>,
{
    matrix
        .rows_par_iter()
        .map(|mut row| {
            row.rw_write(0, 0, 0.0);
        })
        .count();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes the issue clear, and also thanks for the solution.